# After changing ports of apache and mysql is running normal in xampp but myphpadmin is showing these error's

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

mysqli_real_connect(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 21

mysqli_real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 21

mysqli_real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.